# warning: too many arguments for format - fprintf

Tags: c++, c, gcc, warnings

```
    pthread_t      writeToFile = pthread_self ();
    unsigned short iterate;

    for (iterate = 0; iterate < 10000; iterate++)
    {
        fprintf (fp, " %d ",  iterate,     4);
        fprintf (fp, " %lu ", writeToFile, sizeof (pthread_t));
        fprintf (fp, "\n",    writeToFile, 1);
    }
```

In main () `fp = fopen ("xyz", "w");`

Warning: `warning: too many arguments for format`

From here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/

What's wrong in my code?

`gcc version 4.5.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take your first `fprintf`: `" %d "`. it expects one argument (an int), but you give it two - iterate and 4.

It seems like you are adding the size of the data, but you shouldn't. It should probably be:

```
fprintf (fp, " %d ",  iterate);
```

In the other two sentences, it's not even clear what do you want to put in the file.

Comment: Well, writeToFile variable contains the thread Id. Anyway, thanks for helpfing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH `fprintf` does write several things to the file at the same time. fwrite writes only one?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: fwrite takes the size of a single item, and the amount of items to write. Your fprintf invocations look a bit like they have been fwrite previously, and errneously transformed into fprintf.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks again, I'll have to study the differences between fprintf and fwrite, then.

Comment: @AnishaKaul `writeToFile` has type `pthread_t`.  There's no way of outputting this type with `fprintf` (nor with `iostream`, for that matter).

Comment: @JamesKanze actually `pthread_t` has been typedefed as unsigned long, I checked its header file.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Actually, the type of `pthread_t` varies enormously.  You can't count on it being anything in particular.  (Under Solaris, if memory serves me correctly, it's a structure.)